# jQuery animate scrolling without $.browser & not firing twice

Tags: javascript, jquery

I found many questions regarding the cross bowser behaviour of `$('html, body').animate();`, but for some reason I couldn't find an answer for this one:

I want to (finally) remove `$.browser`, but at the same moment don't want the scroll event to be triggered twice again, which will happen in some browsers if the selector is `$('html, body)`

```
// animte page scrolling
pageScroll : function( scrollTo, speed, callback ) {

    var rootElem;

    scrollTo = scrollTo || 0;
    speed = speed || 800;

    if ( $.browser.webkit ) {
        rootElem = $('body');
    } else {
        rootElem = $('html');
    }

    rootElem
        .stop()
        .animate(
            {
                scrollTop: scrollTo
            }, speed, callback
        );
}
```

Comment: What is requirement ?

Comment: scroll between e.g. page sections without firing the event twice; updated my example code, hope that makes it clearer

Comment: Which browsers cause a double trigger on $('html,body')???

Comment: Both do not get triggered, but they *are* being calculated even if one is in vain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've looked into this for quite a while and haven't found a real solution other than a check on doc ready :

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yyddER?editors=011

```
var mainelement;

$('html, body').animate({scrollTop: 1}, 1, function() {

if ($('html').scrollTop()) mainelement = $('html'); // FF and IE
if ($('body').scrollTop()) mainelement = $('body'); // Chrome, Safari and Opera
mainelement.scrollTop(0);
});
```

Assuming here the content is high enough to create a scrollbar...

Tested on the major browsers and works without a hitch.

Edit - a variation to make sure the trigger to scroll the page back is only acted upon a single time if the browser uses `<html>` as the main element for overflow :

```
var mainelement, tested = false;

$('html, body').animate({scrollTop: 1}, 1, function() {

if ($('html').scrollTop()) mainelement = $('html');
else if ($('body').scrollTop()) mainelement = $('body');

if (!tested) {
tested = true;
mainelement.scrollTop(0);
}
});
```

+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

And later came up with **this approach** as well (which seems to be the most efficient) :

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/NPQNEr?editors=001

```
var mainelement;

$(window).scrollTop(1);
if ($('html').scrollTop()) mainelement = $('html');
else if ($('body').scrollTop()) mainelement = $('body');
mainelement.scrollTop(0);
```

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't seem to work with my parameters `speed` and `callback`

Comment: Could you maybe post the combined code then? Must be a detail, can't think of a reason for it to not work. Added a pen in the answer for completeness.

Comment: Thanks. I modified my code based on your example and created a test case: http://codepen.io/scheinercc/pen/NPQxBm - see how `'test animation'` still gets logged twice in IE, but `'actual animation'` will always only gets logged once as I set an extra flag. It is a "tad" more complicated than before with `$.browser` but it seems to work

Comment: if you add something like the flag I set in my example to prevent `mainelement.scrollTop(0);` to be fired twice in IE I can accept your answer. Thanks for your help

Comment: Cheers, added a variation to the answer to prevent such a double trigger. Made me start to think though - so I came up with some code using `$(window).scrollTop()` that may even be a bit more direct.

Comment: Cool. thanks. Merged your 3rd approach into my pen http://codepen.io/scheinercc/pen/NPQxBm

Comment: Looking good, I'm somewhat of a freak for clean code so not having to address both elements at any point seems more elegant.

Answer (score 1):

This is the code I use in production; works just fine:

```
function ScrollPage(TheTop) {

    TheTop = parseInt(TheTop, 10);

    if (!$.isNumeric(TheTop)) { 

      return;
    }

    $('html,body').animate({ scrollTop: TheTop }, 400); 
}
```

If the problem is that the event handler is firing twice then it means the function is somehow called twice, and that the bug is therefore elsewhere. On another note, the `$.browser()` function has been deprecated for a while.

Comment: I think that was the point here -  removing `$.browser` because it has been deprecated for a while. What event handler are you referring to by the way? There are obviously two elements being targeted when using `$('html, body')`. Browsers calculate both (I've tested), even if one is not used for animating.

Comment: Yeah, @Shikkediel has pretty much answered for me already. I think to remember that e.g. IE fires on both, the `html` and the `body` element.